# No content in zip result when invoked metadata soap api in apex

Tags: apex, soap-api, metadata-api

I'm trying to get apex code body by invoking metadata soap api in apex code. I invoked retrieve method, got and resolved response. But in response, i found everything except apex code body, i couldn't get any idea about this, who knows this issue? Please help!
Thanks in advance.

```
       string soapBodyForRetrieve = 
       '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
           '<SOAP-ENV:Header>' +
               '<m:SessionHeader xmlns:m="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
                   + '<m:sessionId>' + Userinfo.getSessionId() + '</m:sessionId>' +
               '</m:SessionHeader>' +
           '</SOAP-ENV:Header>' +
           '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
               '<m:retrieve xmlns:m="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
                   '<m:retrieveRequest>' + 
                       '<m:unpackaged>' +
                           '<m:apiAccessLevel>Unrestricted</m:apiAccessLevel>' +
                           '<m:namespacePrefix>LWG</m:namespacePrefix>' +
                           '<m:types>' +
                               '<m:members>SoapController</m:members>' +
                               '<m:name>ApexClass</m:name>' +
                           '</m:types>' +
                           '<m:version>33</m:version>' +
                       '</m:unpackaged>' +
                   '</m:retrieveRequest>' +
               '</m:retrieve>' +
           '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
       '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
    return soapBodyForRetrieve;
```

Comment: Please show more of your code, so that we see your callout and how you poll the async request. Also add your response (xml dump).

Comment: The metadata only contains the info about the class. To actually get the code, you have to use the retrieve method which gets it as a file that you would need to parse.  The tooling API may be what you want. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf

Comment: Hi, i solved this issue by referencing some javascript plugins. Please check my answer. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, i found we have to reference jszip.js, jszip-load.js, jszip-inflate.js, jszip-deflate.js in javascript, otherwise the compression content will be lost when we parse zip file(base64).

We can find these plugins by this link: https://code.google.com/p/webpagetest/source/browse/trunk/agent/js/node_modules/node-zip/vendor/jszip/?r=1556